# How to use string Resources to populate dropdown list (Spinner) in android

Tags: android, string

Following is my code snippet to populate spinner:

```
prod_cat=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.prod_cat);
String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "three"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
prod_cat.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now instead of populating spinner with "1", "2", and "three", I want to populate it with strings defined in `strings.xml` as shown below:

```
<string name="cat1">Speakers</string>
<string name="cat2">LED</string>
<string name="cat3">Split AC</string>
<string name="cat4">Window AC</string>
```

But when I use following, it says inconvertible types.

```
String s1=(String)R.string.cat1
```

Can anyone help me out how to get string from `R.string.cat1`?

Answer (score 2):

In `strings.xml` create an array of strings like this:

```
<string-array name="str_arr_categories">
    <item>LED</item>
    <item>Speakers</item>
</string-array>
```

And then initialize your `ArrayAdapter` like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.str_arr_categories, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem within no time

Comment: No problem. Mark it as accepted? :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String s1=(String)R.string.cat1
```

with

```
String s1 = mContext.getString(R.string.cat1);
```

where `mContext` is some object that extends the class [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).  Usually, that will be your activity (and if this code is in the Activity class itself, you can just use `this` to refer to it), but in some cases your context could come from other places.